# How to log both to console and file using Python?

Tags: python, logging

I am working Python and I need to logger so I decided to start using RotatingFileHandler. Below is my `logging.conf` file

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=logfile

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=logfile

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=NOTSET
args=('ookagent.log', 'a', 50000000000, 5)
formatter=logfileformatter
```

And below is my Python script from which I am successfully able to log to the files. But I am not sure how to log both to files and console as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

# using RotatingFileHandler for logging purpose
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
ooklogger = logging.getLogger('')


ooklogger.info("HelloWorld")
```

Can we make a change in my logging.conf file by which I can login both to console and files as well? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: This is just for my debugging purpose.. In production I won't use this.. I am testing something and everytime I need to go and look for the files..

Comment: Are you using linux or Mac?

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu 12.04. Forgot to mention..

Comment: Well i think you can use the command tail with the argument -f this in one console this will watch the file and when a new line is added this one will appear in the console for example: tail -f myfile.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the logging configuration file format lets you specify multiple handlers. You can use a `StreamHandler` to log to the console. That would entail modifications like these to your config file:

```
[handlers]
keys=logfile,logconsole

[handler_logconsole]
class=StreamHandler
# other configuration directives as you like

[logger_root]
handlers=logfile,logconsole
```

See the [config file documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried that and it gives me error as `NoOptionError` and I guess I need to add some configuration as you have mentioned in your answer but what configuration I should be adding for logging to console? I am little bit rusty in Python as it is not my first language.

Comment: That's entirely up to you. But as I said, see the documentation for more information and examples.